# Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance > but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to fill a div with data from a json file, I have checked my network tab and it is not inating the request, which is causing the error below, how can I fix this?

Here is my vue component and vue app

```
Vue.component('frontpage', {
    template: '#front',

    data: function(){
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },

    mounted: function(){
        axios.get('front').then(function(posts){
            this.posts = posts;
        }).bind(this);
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#frontpage',
});
```

And my html which is supposed to get the data from a json

```
    <div class="container">
        <frontpage></frontpage>
    </div>

    <div id="frontpage">
        <template id="front">
            <article v-for="post in posts">
                <h1>@{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <div class="body">@{{ post.post }}</div>
            </article>
        </template>
    </div>
```

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.  (found in root instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats), if you are using template in component, you have to provide inline HTML in the template. Given that you are defining the HTML of `frontpage` in HTML, you have to use `el` option to mount the template. You have to make changes like following:

```
Vue.component('frontpage', {
    el: '#front',

    data: function(){
        return {
            posts: []
        }
    },

    mounted: function(){
        axios.get('front').then(function(posts){
            this.posts = posts;
        }).bind(this);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<template id="front">
    <article v-for="post in posts">
       <h1>@{{ post.title }}</h1>
       <div class="body">@{{ post.post }}</div>
    </article>
</template>

<div id="frontpage">
  <div class="container">
     <frontpage></frontpage>
  </div>
</div>
```